# CSS - set border by parent tag

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="col-md-6 parent error">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control my-input">
  </div>
</span>
```

And I would like to set red border to input, when `<div class="parent">` will have class error. I cannot insert error class to input, because `div container` is not my element, it is in component.

I know this:

```
.ngx-datepicker-container > .ngx-datepicker-input{
    border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

but it set red border, always. I need only when `parent` div will have error class.

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are closing `div` tag with `span` tag. As for your question use `.error input` selector. If there will be error class it will work, else it won't:

```css
.error input{
    border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 parent error">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control my-input">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
.parent.error input {
    border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use

```html
<div class="parent error">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
div.parent.error input {
 border: 1px solid red;
```

}